# How to remove entries with export from bash history?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, xargs

I'm trying to remove entries from the bash `history` which contain `export`. I think I'm not so far from the solution. So far I have:

`history | grep export | awk '{print $1}' | sort -r | xargs -I {} bash -c "echo 'Deleting [{}]' && history -d {}"`

- `history` = get history line id + line content
- `grep export` = filter on lines containing "export"
- `awk '{print $1}'` = print only the line id
- `sort -r` = sort line ids in descending order (otherwise when deleting earlier ids, all subsequent ones get shifted)
- `xargs -I {} bash -c "echo 'Deleting [{}]' && history -d {}"` = for each line id, run the history delete fn

**When I troubleshoot each part of the command I seem to be getting what I need, however overall it's still failing saying the lines I'm trying to delete are out of range.**

**Can someone please help me finish this command please?**

Comment: `grep | awk` is an anti-pattern.  Instead of `grep pattern | awk '{cmd}'`, use `awk '/pattern/{cmd}'`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an easier approach would be to filter and delete directly from the `history` file.

```
$ sed -i.bak '/\<export\>/d' "$HISTFILE"
```

I have wrapped the filtered word in word boundaries, but can be adjusted to suit your filtering requirements.

A backup is also created in case you need to roll back.

```
$ cat "$HISTFILE"
```

will then show you the new history file. If happy with the removed entries, reload history for the changes to take effect globally.

```
$ history -r
```

Comment: This will ruin the history file if time stamp information associated with each history entry is saved in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have multi-line strings that include `export` in your history. I'll assume that you want to delete the related commands too.

The following solution isn't bullet proof but it should work for most cases:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# makes sure that the output of 'history' isn't messed up
HISTTIMEFORMAT=''

# needed for editing the history from a script
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
set -o history

# parse and modify the history
while IFS='' read -r id
do
    echo "deleting $id from history"
    history -d "$id"
done < <(
    history |
    awk '
        /^ *[1-9][0-9]* +/ { id = $1 }
        /export/ && !seen[id]++ { list[++n] = id }
        END { for (i = n; i >= 1; i--) print list[i] }
    '
)
```

<sup>**remark:** As you're already using `bash` and `awk` you don't need to call `sort` nor `xargs`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you want (you should run these commands from command line, since `HISTFILE` most likely is unset for non-interactive shells):

```
mapfile -t offsets < <(history | awk '/export/{print $1 - n++}')
for offset in "${offsets[@]}"; do history -d "$offset"; done
history -w
```

Backup the original history file (usually `~/.bash_history`) before running this.